# MS Project 2013 Task Usage Jumping

Tags: ms-project, arrow-keys

In Excel, you can use the CTRL and arrow keys to jump from the current cell to the next cell that contains data making it really efficient to jump around a large sparsely populated worksheet. Is there similar functionality in MS Project for instance in the task usage view to jump to the dates that contain data quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic but I'm leaving this to others to decide.

Comment: Have I committed a stackoverflow sin?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be the equivalent arrow key functionality in Project.